# Symfonys: Model with array field is not possible to show in Twig

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a Model:

```
class SearchOfferFacet
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $id;

/**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $country;

//getters ans setters....
```

And I have a FormType

```
... 

$builder
            ->add('country', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'choices_as_values' => true,
                'choices' => array('US' => "USA", "IT" => "Italia"),
            ))
```

When I create the form in my controller with

```
$searchOfferFacet = new SearchOfferFacet();
$searchOfferFacet->setCountry(
            array(
                'US' => 'US',
                'MV' => 'MV'
            )
        );
$form = $this->createForm(SearchOfferFacetType::class, $searchOfferFacet, array('method' => 'POST'));
```

I get the following Exception:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 13.
```

But when I change the variable in my model to String, and I set a string as Country, for example "US", then the exception appears:

```
 Expected an array.
```

In my TWIG there is nothing special, just:

```
{{ form_widget(form.country) }}
```

Does anyone has an idea what is wrong?

Comment: What a strange array declaration in FormType. I think you made a typo by putting "$" symbol before "array" keyword.

Comment: is `$array('US' => "USA", "IT" => "Italia"),`  a typo when you write the question or did you have the same in your code?

Comment: Sorry $ is not in my code

Comment: Could you try `{{ form_row(form.country) }}`  instead of `{{ form_widget(form.country) }}` ? Then, please, tell us if error still appears. You can also check your server's php error log. Sometimes symfony says "line x in twig", but deeply, error is origin in another line of your code.

Comment: The error is the same when i change it on form_row: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 13.". But even when I make only {{ form(form) }} in my TWIG Template there is the same error.

Comment: @Zwen2012 how about your server log? Did it tell something about this error?

Comment: In my dev.log: request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in "form_div_layout.html.twig" at line 13." at /vagrant/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 4809 {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Runtime(code: 0): An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template (\"Notice: Array to string conversion\") in \"form_div_layout.html.twig\" at line 13. at /vagrant/app/cache/dev/classes.php:4809, Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException(code: 0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114192/discussion-between-muriano-and-zwen2012).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting `'multiple' => true,`? My suspicion here is that you the member is an array, but since you set `'multiple' => false,`, it only needs to save a string.

On the other hand, you can then also just do

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $country;
```

and the `setCountry(...)` function should only save a string.